# CI/CD with stream jobs build in AZURE Portal

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am new to Azure and Azure Deployment.

I followed below steps and I am confused what to do next:

- Using the link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-vs-tools ,I opened the solution in VS 2017
- Now ,I am following the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-visual-studio-cicd-vsts
- Now as it say that we need to add 'you need to use the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD.'

but when I add in VS it give me below error :
[image]

Then ,

- Created a projects in DEVOPS,Created Repos and then cloned it to VISUAL STUDIO
- In the visual studio ,opened the project and try to sync it
- After clicking on sync button it gives me option to PUSH it to Devops

  I have 2 questions :

1) But even i push it to DEVOPS,it doesn't include 'NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD'what should I do.

2) Second question is I am doing CI/CD through Visual studio,SO if I make any changes in stream job directly in PORTAL it will not get reflected,unless i make same changes in VS right?

Answer (score 0):

for question #1, you can not using the nuget command to install the nuget package as you do for dotnet based project, what you should do is following the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-visual-studio-cicd-vsts

**Configure NuGet package dependency**

```
Add packages.config to your project directory.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

for question #2, that is correct. The change you did in portal will be recorded in Azure RP service. The configurations(json files) in VS project are the source codes for your asa project, so you need check in them and redeploy it to cloud to make it take effect.

Comment: Hi Joe,How to add Packages.config ?,as when i right click on the solution to add new items it doesn't give me option for config?

Comment: Refer to the link below:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21873
It tells that"The CI.CD nuget package is to be used on an arbitrary machine, not inside VS. It is not supported to add nuget package to Stream Analytics Visual Studio project at this moment."

And I was not able to add Package.config,So i right click on project and added existing Config file from difference project and replaced the content with <?xml
 version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package
id="Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD"
version="1.0.0"
targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>

Comment: actually you did not need add it as part of your asa project and just put in project root folder and treat it as your source code.

Comment: what do you mean by put in Project root folder and treat it as your source code?.i add the package.config in the solution

Comment: it is not necessary to be one part one VS solution or project that means you do not need add it through "add new items" from VS UI.  But you should check in this file to your source code. when you do the deployment, you can use it as you should deploy based on project source code.